# SQL Modification

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a query (Main Query) is like this. I am executing this in Toad connected to Netezza DB.

```
SELECT *
  FROM db1.schema1.Table1
WHERE (pd_num, pd_num_mtr, pd_num_prefix, sqr_num) IN
          (SELECT pd_num,
                  pd_num_mtr,
                  pd_num_prefix,
                  max (sqr_num) sqr_num
             FROM db1.schema1.table1
            WHERE create_date >= '01/01/2012' AND cd_operator <> 'N'
           GROUP BY pd_num, pd_num_mtr, pd_num_prefix)
```

When I execute this I get some 1 million records as my output. I further executed a query (Query2) to analyze the number of records belonging to the group as follows.

```
select pd_num_mtr,pd_num_prefix,count(*)
from db1.schema1.table1 
GROUP BY pd_num, pd_num_mtr
order by count(*) desc
```

I get the below out put for this.

```
pd_num pd_num_mtr count(*)
001      15          500
002      15          200
003      30          100
```

Which means I have some 500 records pulled for the pd_num and pd_num_mtr combination with each of these records having an update_timestamp value. Now this needs to be modified as follows.

So among these 500 records, I need to pull only the one with maximum update_timestamp which will limit the count to only 1 record instead of 500.1 from 200 records, 1 record from 100 records with the max update timestamp value.

How can I modify the first query (main query) to acheive this? So that if the run the query2, I get the below as the output.

```
pd_num pd_num_mtr count(*)
001        15          1
002        15          2
003        30          3
```

Appreciate your help again. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to pull 1 record from each group, why would the counts be 1,2,3 instead of 1,1,1?

Answer (score 1):

We will have to use row_number function for this. Assuming 'update_timestamp' as your timestamp column.

```
SELECT PD_NUM_MTR,PD_NUM_PREFIX 
FROM
(
   SELECT PD_NUM_MTR,PD_NUM_PREFIX,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PD_NUM_MTR,PD_NUM_PREFIX  ORDER BY update_timestamp desc ) AS RK
   FROM DB1.SCHEMA1.TABLE1 
)
WHERE RK=1;
```

Comment: Thanks. So How should the main to be modified?